# Inconsistent behavior with sympify when evaluating expressions with relational operators

Tags: python, sympy

When I parse an expression with a greater than operator using sympify, I get an expression with StrictGreaterThan as the root.  However, substituting an `==` operator, `sympify` evaluates the expression to a boolean False. How do I keep sympy from evaluating the expression with `==` so that I get a general expression as I do with `>` operator?

```
from sympy import *

In [2]: s1 = 'a - 4 > b + 5'

In [3]: expr1 = sympify(s1)

In [4]: type(expr1)

Out[4]: sympy.core.relational.StrictGreaterThan

In [5]: s2 = 'a - 4 == b + 5'

In [6]: expr2 = sympify(s2)

In [7]: type(expr2)

Out[7]: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I solved this while using sympy is to bring the RHS to LHS and then sympify() the string.
i.e. changing `LHS == RHS` to `LHS - RHS`

```
exprStr =  'a - 4 == b + 5'
indOfEq = exprStr.find('==')
if indOfEq != -1:
   splitExpr  = exprStr.split('=')
   if len(splitExpr)==2:
      exprStr = splitExpr[0]+'-('+splitExpr[1]+')'
expr2 = sympify(exprStr )
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in http://docs.sympy.org/dev/gotchas.html,

> Double equals signs (==) are used to test equality. However, this
>   tests expressions exactly, not symbolically.

You can use `sympy.Eq`, as in

```
In [54]: sympy.Eq(sympy.abc.a - 3, sympy.abc.b + 5)
Out[54]: a - 3 == b + 5

In [55]: sympy.GreaterThan(sympy.abc.a - 3, sympy.abc.b + 5)
Out[55]: a - 3 >= b + 5
```

Anyway, it really seems inconsistent.